# What packages get added when you run ng eject?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run `ng eject` command, I see below messages printed on the console. In the last line, it says it has added packages? What packages get added when we run `ng eject`? I'm using angular CLI version 1.0.6.

```
To run your builds, you now need to do the following commands:
   - "npm run build" to build.
   - "npm run test" to run unit tests.
   - "npm start" to serve the app using webpack-dev-server.
   - "npm run e2e" to run protractor.

Running the equivalent CLI commands will result in an error.

==========================================================================================

Some packages were added. Please run "npm install".
```

Answer (score 0):

After Eject

run `npm install` to add **webpack**

Webpack is the bundler that Angular CLI now uses to pack your files when build.

For documentation look at here:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/

And Angular integration documentation here:
https://angular.io/guide/webpack